# Can NSTableView handle normal drag-and-drop methods?

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsdragginginfo

I'd like to use NSTableView without [the NSTableViewDataSource Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/UsingDragAndDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000726-BABFIDAB) but just like a normal view. `draggingEntered:` and `draggingExited:` are being called but when I return `NSDragOperationCopy`, I don't see the green plus mouse pointer and `performDragOperation:` doesn't get called.

I subclassed the NSTableView with these methods:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject: NSFilenamesPboardType]];
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered: (id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSLog(@"draggingEntered"); //Gets called
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (void)draggingExited: (id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSLog(@"draggingExited"); //Gets called
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation: (id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSLog(@"performDragOperation"); //Doesn't get called
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says it conforms to the NSDraggingDestination and NSDraggingSource protocol, so yes it should hand normal drag-and-drop.

You might try using -registerForDraggedTypes: method from nsview.

Comment: I tried that, otherwise `draggingEntered:` and `draggingExited:` wouldn't be called.